# Group by column with preference for rows in which another column is not null

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group, sql-null

Say I have a table which looks like this, with two foreign keys:

```
| col1 | fkey1 | fkey2 |
|------|-------|-------|
| foo  | 123   | null  |
| foo  | 123   | 456   |
| bar  | 789   | null  |
```

How would I group by `col1`, with a preference for the row in which `fkey2` **is not** `null`? So that the result would look like this:

```
| col1 | fkey1 | fkey2 |
|------|-------|-------|
| foo  | 123   | 456   |
| bar  | 789   | null  |
```

One other consideration is that `fkey1` has a `not null` constraint on it, while `fkey2` does not.

Comment: Is `fkey2` defined `UNIQUE`? If not, which row to pick from peers with distinct non-null values? Will more columns be involved? The question would be much more useful with a `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

For this dataset, you *could* use simple aggregation:

```
select col1, fkey1, max(fkey2) fkey2
from mytable
group by col1, fkey1
```

But I suspect that you actually want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on(col1) t.*
from mytable t
order by col1, fkey2
```